# Any side effect to remove the null handler from event?

Tags: c#, .net

I am wondering before removing the handler

OnEvent -= handler;

Do we need to determine if the handler is the null or not. When handler is null, is there any bad effect?

Comment: tried, looks like no bad effect apparently. But want to make sure with the expert here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, if `handler` is null it's a no-op... or at least, it will be if it's a simple call to [`Delegate.Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx), which has documentation including:

> Returns *source* if *value* is null or if the invocation list of *value* is not found within the invocation list of *source*.

Now an actual *event* just has a "remove" method effectively... and that *can* do anything it wants. It would be a pretty poorly-implemented event which had an ill effect when passed a null handler though, as null effectively means "an empty invocation list" in delegate terms.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not a problem. It's like removing a non existing item of a collection. Nothing happens.